# canvas.drawText with pixel perfect text on a canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawtext, android-typeface, pixel-perfect

> **THIS IS NOT ABOUT AntiAlias, Please read the question before answering thank you.**

ADDING BOUNTY TO--> [android convert text width (in pixels) to percent of screen width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7429033/1815624)

Quality info --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/1815624

I am getting inconsistent results when trying to draw text on a canvas.  Please help, thank you.

I want the text to consume the same amount of scaled space on all devices

I do not care about ANTI_ALIAS and have added the `paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);` but the problem is the same...

On 1 screen the text consumes half the width, on another only a 1/3 and even one that uses the full width.

**I want them all to use equal amounts of screen real estate.**

For Example

1600X900 7inch tablet Kitkat physical:
[image: inconsistent results]

1920.1080 5.2 kitkat physical
[image: inconsistent results]

1600x900 20in Lollipop emulated
[image: inconsistent results]

1280x720 4.7inch
[image: inconsistent results]

These have been created using the guide at http://www.gkproggy.com/2013/01/draw-text-on-canvas-with-font-size.html

where as that tutorial is showing consistent results 
[image: consistent results]

To be thorough here is the source:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Paint paint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        paint = new Paint();
        View test = new TestView(this);

        setContentView(test);
    }

    public class TestView extends View
    {

        public TestView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }

        public float pixelsToSp(Context context, float px) {
            float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
            return px/scaledDensity;
        }

        public float spToPixels(float sp) {
            Context context = getContext();
            float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
            return scaledDensity*sp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sp20);
            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            Log.v("intSize", Integer.toString(size));
            Log.v("intSize", Integer.toString(px));
            Log.v("intSize", Float.toString(spToPixels(20f)));
            if(true) {
                Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Ultra.ttf");
                paint.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            }
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(size);
            paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            canvas.drawText("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!", 0, size, paint);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried suggestion from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369766/1815624

Looking into this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895626/1815624

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14753968/1815624

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895626/1815624 <-- trying now

Comment: I don't really know what you're asking, but to get 'smooth' edges you can set anti aliasing to true on the paint object

Comment: I want the text to consume the same amount of scaled space on all devices

Comment: It sure looks like they do. Do you want them to span the same *percentage* of the screen width / height or that they are the same size if you were measuring them with a ruler?

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to do. percentage

Comment: The text seems to be about the same size as the status bar on every screenshot you provide...It scales correctly.

Comment: sorry I want percentage of screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102167/discussion-between-crandellws-and-david-medenjak).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources used:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4847027/1815624

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21895626/1815624

Got to get screen width, some reference of text size to screen ratio, and calculate.  so the results are:

[image: better results]

and

[image: better results]

***notice the second HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Paint paint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        paint = new Paint();
        View test = new TestView(this);

        setContentView(test);
    }

    public class TestView extends View
    {

        public TestView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        }

        public float pixelsToSp(float px) {
            Context context = getContext();
            float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
            return px/scaledDensity;
        }

        public float spToPixels(float sp) {
            Context context = getContext();
            float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
            return scaledDensity*sp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            int size = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sp20);
            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            Log.v("intSize", Integer.toString(size));
            Log.v("intSize", Integer.toString(px));
            Log.v("intSize", Float.toString(spToPixels(20f)));

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

            Log.v("intSize hm", Integer.toString(metrics.heightPixels));
            Log.v("intSize wm", Integer.toString(metrics.widthPixels));

            if(true) {
                Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Ultra.ttf");
                paint.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            }
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(size);
            paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            canvas.drawText("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!", 0, size, paint);
            setTextSizeForWidth(paint, metrics.widthPixels * 0.5f, "HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!");
            canvas.drawText("HELLOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!", 0, size*3, paint);
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
        /**
         * Sets the text size for a Paint object so a given string of text will be a
         * given width.
         *
         * @param paint
         *            the Paint to set the text size for
         * @param desiredWidth
         *            the desired width
         * @param text
         *            the text that should be that width
         */
        private void setTextSizeForWidth(Paint paint, float desiredWidth,
                                                String text) {

            // Pick a reasonably large value for the test. Larger values produce
            // more accurate results, but may cause problems with hardware
            // acceleration. But there are workarounds for that, too; refer to
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253528/font-size-too-large-to-fit-in-cache
            final float testTextSize = 48f;

            // Get the bounds of the text, using our testTextSize.
            paint.setTextSize(testTextSize);
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

            // Calculate the desired size as a proportion of our testTextSize.
            float desiredTextSize = testTextSize * desiredWidth / bounds.width();

            // Set the paint for that size.
            paint.setTextSize(desiredTextSize);
        }

    }
}
```

please note if you not extending Activity use

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

instead of

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```